# ngx-datatable - how to add 'actions' column

Tags: angular, datatable

I'm experimenting with ngx-datatables (Angular2) and have what I think is a simple question ... How do I add an additional 'actions' column - you know the column which is typically the last column in a table (aka after the data) which contains 'action' links (i.e. 'edit', 'delete', etc ...) ?

I've got the demo's running locally - so if there'a a demo in the project's demo - just direct me there.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

If you specify one ngx-datatable-column, you will have to specify them all. That is why everything works fine in case of no explicit column.

It should work fine if you add the other columns explicitly - no need to add the template:

..